# Dart create a Map of entries from a List

Tags: list, dart, dictionary, dto

During the creation of my DTO, i have to convert a List of objects to a Map of another DTO.
The List is looking like so:

`final List badgesList = [BadgeItem_1, BadgeItem_2, BadgeItem_3, ...]`

I want to convert this to the primitive entry: `Map<String, BadgeItemDto>? badges` directly inside the declaration.

Currenlty I did it like so:

```
return CardDto(
      badges: badgesList!
          .map(
            (badgeItem) => <String, BadgeItemDto>{
              badgeItem.id: BadgeItemDto.fromDomain(badgeItem)
            },
          )
```

However, this is returning a `List<Map<String, BadgeItemDto>>` instead of `Map<String, BadgeItemDto>`. How can I basically have a singleMap with Map as the values created directly in the declaration?

The final outcome should look like this

```
{'abcdefgh': 
        {'id': '1234', 'badgeName': 'Lorem ipsum', ...}
 'ztrewq': 
        {'id': '6432', 'badgeName': 'Lorem ipsum', ...}
}
```

To be complete, this is how the BadgeItemDTO is looking:

```
abstract class BadgeItemDto implements _$BadgeItemDto {
  const factory BadgeItemDto({
    required String badgeId,
    required String badgeName,
  
  }) = _BadgeItemDto;
  factory BadgeItemDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$BadgeItemDtoFromJson(json);
  const BadgeItemDto._();

  factory BadgeItemDto.fromDomain(BadgeItem badgeItem) {
    return BadgeItemDto(
      badgeId: badgeItem.id.getOrCrash(),
      badgeName: badgeItem.badgeName.getOrCrash(),
    );
  }

  BadgeItem toDomain() {
    return BadgeItem(
      id: UniqueId.fromUniqueString(badgeId),
      badgeName: BadgeName(badgeName),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in the following ways:

```
void main() {
  final items = [
    BadgeItem('10', 'name 1'),
    BadgeItem('20', 'name 2'),
    BadgeItem('30', 'name 3'),
  ];
  
  final map = items.asMap().map((k, v) => MapEntry(v.id, v));
  final map2 = Map.fromEntries(items.map((v) => MapEntry(v.id, v)));
  print(map);
  print(map2);
}

class BadgeItem {
  const BadgeItem(this.id, this.name);
  
  final String id;
  final String name;
}
```

1. Convert the List to a Map, and then map it with new [Map Entries](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.2/dart-core/MapEntry/MapEntry.html).
2. Create a [Map.fromEntries](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.1/dart-core/Map/Map.fromEntries.html), where for each element you create a [Map Entry](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.2/dart-core/MapEntry/MapEntry.html).

Comment: Tank you. So I cannot directly can do this during the declaration of my variables but have to do it in a sperate function returning then the map?

Comment: You can directly assign a new variable with it, as you can see my example is doing exactly that. It's assigning map to value of Map<String, BadgeItem> by using items collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
final List badgesList = [BadgeItem_1, BadgeItem_2, BadgeItem_3, ...]
final result = <String,BadgeItemDto>{
  for (final item in badgesList)
    (something to make the String from item) :
    (something to make the BadgeItemDto from item),
  };
```

Just like that.  Use a collection literal for-loop-element.
People are still working far too hard trying to get .map to work for them.  Useful in streams, but not so much when you have all the values in hand already.